Distinguishing Between Trigonometric Quantum States
In my quantum system, I have quantum inputs represented in two forms:
$$
|G^h * x \rangle_c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{T}} \sum_{g \in \mathbb{Z}_N} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi gh}{N}\right) |g * x \rangle
$$
$$
|G^h * x \rangle_s = \frac{1}{\sqrt{T}} \sum_{g \in \mathbb{Z}_N} \sin\left(\frac{2\pi gh}{N}\right) |g * x \rangle
$$
where $( g * x )$ denotes a group action on the element $x$. I am seeking a quantum algorithm or circuit that can distinguish between these two states, $|G^h * x \rangle_c $ and $ |G^h * x \rangle_s $, preferably without destroying the input state. Any suggestions or references to relevant quantum algorithms would be greatly appreciated!
Edit 1:
So I'm working on Quantum Money from Abelian Group Actions from Mark Zhandry. So By group action we mean cryptographic group actions with the following properties:

Regular: For every $y \in X_\lambda$, there is exactly one $g \in {G}_\lambda$ such that $y = g \ast x_\lambda$.
Cryptographic group actions: A group action that satisfies the DLog assumption.
Efficiently computable: There is a QPT procedure $\text{Construct}$ which, on input $1^\lambda$, outputs a description of ${G}_\lambda$ and an element $x_\lambda \in {X}_\lambda$. The operation $\ast$ is also computable by a QPT algorithm.
Efficiently Recognizable: There is a QPT procedure $\text{Recog}$ which recognizes elements in ${X}_\lambda$. That is, for any $\lambda$ and any string $y$ (not necessarily in ${X}_\lambda$), $\text{Recog}(1^\lambda, y)$ accepts $y$ with overwhelming probability if $y \in {X}_\lambda$, and rejects with overwhelming probability if $y \not\in {X}_\lambda$.

Edit 2:
I think these two states are orthogonal. The inner product between these two states, as Tristan mentioned, is:
$$
\left\langle G^h*x\middle|G^h*x\right\rangle = \sum_{g\in\mathbb{Z}_N}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi g h}{N}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi g h}{N}\right) =
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{g\in\mathbb{Z}_N}\sin\left(\frac{4\pi g h}{N}\right)
$$
This summation is always zero because we have [ref]:
$$
\begin{split}R \triangleq \frac{\sin(N \frac{1}{2}d)}{\sin(\frac{1}{2} d)} \\
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \cos(a + nd) =
\begin{cases}
N \cos a & \text{if } \sin(\frac{1}{2}d) = 0 \\
R \cos ( a + (N - 1) \frac{1}{2} d) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sin(a + nd) =
\begin{cases}
N \sin a & \text{if } \sin(\frac{1}{2}d) = 0 \\
R \sin ( a + (N - 1) \frac{1}{2} d) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\end{split}
$$
In the formula, $a$ is zero. Also, $R$ is always zero unless $d = 0$. But when $d = 0$, the sum is $N \sin(a)$ which is zero again.

Do you have any specific group action in mind? Or any restriction on the set on which the group action acts?

@TristanNemoz I updated the post.

The only property you need is that of regularity. It ensures that $\left\{|g*x\rangle\right\}_{g\in\mathbb{Z}_N}$ is an orthonormal basis, since $g\mapsto g*x$ is bijective.
The optimal probability to distinguish between two states is known: in your case this probability is equal to:
$$\begin{align}\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1-|{}_c\left\langle G^h*x\middle|G^h*x\right\rangle_s|}&=\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1-\sum_{g\in\mathbb{Z}_N}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi g h}{N}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi g h}{N}\right)}\\&=\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1-\frac12\sum_{g\in\mathbb{Z}_N}\sin\left(\frac{4\pi g h}{N}\right)}\,.\end{align}$$
As mentioned in the comments, this sum is actually nil, which means that these states are orthogonal.
As such, not only you can perfectly distinguish them, but you can do so without disturbing them.
Indeed, since they are orthogonal, there is a unitary such that $U|0\rangle$ yields the first state, and $U|1\rangle$ yields the second one. Thus, you can apply $U^\dagger$ to your state and measure it. If you get $|0\rangle$, then the first state is the one that was given to you. If you get $|1\rangle$, it was the other one. Finally, you can apply $U$ to recover the original state.

However, they are orthogonal because this summation is zero. Take a look at this. In the formula, $a$ is zero. Also, $R$ is always zero unless $d = 0$. But when $d = 0$, the sum is $N \sin(a)$ which is zero again.

@Morteza Thanks! I've edited my answer accordingly
